# How c# handles JSON object similiar to javascript without define object class before parsing

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON response : {"status" : "true"}

How do I get the value "true" in c# without defining any class?

Comment: You should add more information about your issue.

Comment: Use a library. Json.NET can parse to a class or to a standard Dictionary or to XML or to .. it can parse in many ways. So can the standard .NET serializer, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in many ways. I usually do this with Json.Net like this:

```
string jsonString = "{\"status\" : \"true\"}";
dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(dyn.status); //prints true
```

Json.Net: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: The dynamic conversion return an ExpandoObject instance, right?